# How to create and edit the excel file using javascript?

Tags: excel, javascript

How to create and edit the excel file using javascript? Is there a library for javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [exceljs library](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) looks quite nice and has all the feature I need. I have selected it for a future project but not tested in depth yet.  It's available thru npm but I guess it can be made to work in other cases.

Comment: Is it possible to use vba?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question.  If you mean adding vba modules and such, I know of no library to do that.  If that's not the question, then can you give more details ?